# How to access original single entries after map and reduce

Tags: javascript, reduce

Given the following function:

```
var files = [file1,file2,file3]    
files.map(doSomethingWithFile).reduce(function (sequence, filePromise) {
    return sequence.then(function () {
      return filePromise;
    }).then(function (content, err) {
        //doSomethingWith(file,content)   <-- How to access current file (either file1,file2 or file3)
    });
```

How can I access 'file' which would be a single element out of files?
As 'then' is guaranteed to have it sorted, I know that the first time I enter the last then, file1 is the element to map with. After that file2, file3...

However, is there any other way than having an increasing index to directly do something with the original file and the result?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking - but map and reduce do not modify in place, so the original files array still exists.

Comment: Thanks! I know that they are not modifying in place. I was just wondering if there is an easy way to combine result and original item without having to store them in an array and map them together manually.

Comment: you can pass a third argument to reduce which is the current index of the array in question.  that should allow you to access the current files index for files.

Comment: Thanks Jonah, I would like to accept this if you post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map and reduce do not modify in place, so the original files array still exists.  Additionally, you can pass a third parameter to reduce, which is the current index.  You can use this parameter to access the corresponding element of the original array

```
var files = [file1,file2,file3]    

files
  .map(doSomethingWithFile)
  .reduce(function(sequence, filePromise, i) {
    return sequence.then(function() {
      return filePromise;
    }).then(function (content, err) {
      doSomethingWith(file[i], content)   // i comes from .reduce()
});
```

Comment: Cheers, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Have your map function return a wrapper object that contains references to both the file and the promise.

i.e....

```
function doSomethingWithFile(file){
  //do something
  return {file:file, promise:...}
}
files.map(doSomethingWithFiles).reduce(function(sequence, wrapper){
  wrapper.file;
  wrapper.promise;
});
```